# What's the function of the word "si" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

What's the function of the word *si* here at the beginning of this sentence

> Les oiseaux (ou classe des Aves) sont des vertébrés tétrapodes ailés
>   appartenant au clade des dinosaures. **S**'il existe près de 10 000
>   espèces d'oiseaux, très différentes tant par leur écologie que par
>   leurs comportements, chacune d'elles présente un ensemble commun de
>   caractéristiques évidentes permettant de les regrouper.

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oiseau

It seems to me that it is unnecesary. I don't get how the meaning of the sentence changes thanks to that word.

Answer (score 11):

Here *si* doesn't introduce a condition but a concession, you can also use *bien que* for that meaning.  You could render it in English with *while* or *although*.

Answer (score 3):

Oddly, this construction is exactly the same as a standard ‘condition followed by statement’ construction:

> si [propositiοn1], [proposition2]

but its meaning is completely different. I would expand it as follows:

> il est vrai que [propositiοn1], mais notez bien que [proposition2].

This construction is only used when the first proposition is presented like a fact and when it is outright obvious that it cannot be a condition.

Comment: Just to clarify, the fact that there is no possible confusion here is because of the "présent de vérité générale" which could never be use as the antecedent of a conditional statement.

Comment: @a3nm: How do you recognize a “présent de vérité générale”. Si tu sais faire ça, je veux bien savoir comment tu fais :-)

Answer (score 2):

Je pense qu'en anglais on pourrait employer « whereas » or « though » pour traduire « si » (dans le cas présent).

On a donc tendance à comprendre que « si » montre le paradoxe entre un nombre très élevé (d'espèces d'oiseaux) et des caractéristiques singulières que l'on retrouve pourtant communes à toutes les espèces... Mais la suite invalide cette compréhension, puisqu'elle signifie : « chaque espèce présente des caractéristiques communes à tous les membres de l'espèce » (CQFD, donc inutile en effet).

Mon avis est que les termes « chacune » autant que « si » sont mal employés. La personne qui a écrit ce texte souhaitait vraisemblablement nous éclairer sur le mode de définition des espèces, et n'y est pas parvenue : on définit une espèce par des caractéristiques précises communes; des différences très marquées ayant été observées, étudiées etc. ceci explique en définitive un nombre d'espèces très élevé.

Donc comme vous l'écrivez, non seulement le « si » est inutile, mais c'est toute la syntaxe de la phrase qui est à revoir, puisqu'elle dessert le message final.